# Need guidance to start working on Openfire through strophe

Tags: chat, openfire, strophe

My objective is to get communication started on openfire through strophe. But have a few questions like:

What is the language that strophe will be written in?

How and where are the connections written?

Just some basic guidance or a good link to a starter tutorial will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strophe is a javascript library here is a good link to get you started.

http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/